# split web traffic 10% to a new site version and 90% to old?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, load-balancing

What if a have a site: **test.com** and I've developed a new version of that site. And I need to test-drive it first before launching it full-scale. So I want to split web traffic 10% to a new site version and 90% to old.

Is that possible and how should I approach that?

P.S. typical lamp stack: linux+apache2+mysql. 1 big physical server (40gb of RAM?).

Answer (score 2):

You can setup either *nginx* or *varnish cache* as a reverse proxy in front of your Apache2 web-site, and configure it to do the appropriate splitting of the traffic.

Depending on whether the new version of your site is or is not compatible with the old one, you might want to ensure that a given user or an IP-address is always given either the old version of the site, or the new one; unless your whole idea revolves around a complete mix-and-match.

---

With nginx, you can use the [http `upstream` module](http://nginx.org/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html), and assign distinct `weight` to different backends, where each Apache backend would serve a specific version of the site.  The module also has the `ip_hash` directive, so that you can specify whether you want to highly increase the likelihood that a given client would see the same version of the site.

The nginx configuration also has support for reading cookies; if the above `upstream` module is not enough by itself, you could also create some extra opt-in/opt-out logic through the cookies, and have nginx make the traffic split based on the content of the cookies.